# How can I obtain an XML element's text from Zillow API response output using R?

Tags: r, xml, zillow

I am working with response output from Zillow's API service in R; it appears to be in an XML format and I would like to obtain the text from a certain element in the response. However, when I attempted to parse the XML file using xmlTreeParse, an error occurs, stating "XML content does not seem to be XML". How can I obtain the text of a certain element in the API response?

I am a bit of a novice with R, so any method or advice regarding how to convert this response or obtain an element's text would be awesome. I think the problem lies in the format of the API response.

```
library(ZillowR)
library(XML)
library(RCurl)

## one must have a "zws_id", Zillow's API key ##

reply <- GetDeepSearchResults(address = '33 Pratt Rd', citystatezip = 'Scituate, MA',
  rentzestimate = FALSE, zws_id = "XXXXXX",
  url = "http://www.zillow.com/webservice/GetDeepSearchResults.htm")

reply

doc = xmlTreeParse(reply, asText = TRUE, useInternal = TRUE)
xmlValue(doc[["//amount"]])
```

"reply" output

```
$request
$request$address
[1] "33 Pratt Rd"

$request$citystatezip
[1] "Scituate, MA"


$message
$message$text
[1] "Request successfully processed"

$message$code
[1] "0"


$response
<response>
 <results>
  <result>
   <zpid>57223487</zpid>
   <links>
    <homedetails>http://www.zillow.com/homedetails/33-Pratt-Rd-Scituate-MA-02066/57223487_zpid/</homedetails>
    <graphsanddata>http://www.zillow.com/homedetails/33-Pratt-Rd-Scituate-MA-02066/57223487_zpid/#charts-and-data</graphsanddata>
    <mapthishome>http://www.zillow.com/homes/57223487_zpid/</mapthishome>
    <comparables>http://www.zillow.com/homes/comps/57223487_zpid/</comparables>
   </links>
   <address>
    <street>33 Pratt Rd</street>
    <zipcode>02066</zipcode>
    <city>Scituate</city>
    <state>MA</state>
    <latitude>42.211625</latitude>
    <longitude>-70.775096</longitude>
   </address>
   <FIPScounty>25023</FIPScounty>
   <useCode>SingleFamily</useCode>
   <taxAssessmentYear>2019</taxAssessmentYear>
   <taxAssessment>441300.0</taxAssessment>
   <yearBuilt>1972</yearBuilt>
   <lotSizeSqFt>21400</lotSizeSqFt>
   <finishedSqFt>1363</finishedSqFt>
   <bathrooms>1.0</bathrooms>
   <bedrooms>3</bedrooms>
   <totalRooms>6</totalRooms>
   <zestimate>
    <amount currency="USD">472759</amount>
    <last-updated>06/16/2019</last-updated>
Calling 'structure(NULL, *)' is deprecated, as NULL cannot have attributes.
  Consider 'structure(list(), *)' instead.    <oneWeekChange deprecated="true"/>
    <valueChange duration="30" currency="USD">2131</valueChange>
    <valuationRange>
     <low currency="USD">449121</low>
     <high currency="USD">501125</high>
    </valuationRange>
    <percentile>0</percentile>
   </zestimate>
   <localRealEstate>
    <region name="Scituate" id="397319" type="city">
     <zindexValue>551,000</zindexValue>
     <links>
      <overview>http://www.zillow.com/local-info/MA-Scituate/r_397319/</overview>
      <forSaleByOwner>http://www.zillow.com/scituate-ma/fsbo/</forSaleByOwner>
      <forSale>http://www.zillow.com/scituate-ma/</forSale>
     </links>
    </region>
   </localRealEstate>
  </result>
 </results>
</response>
```

It is a bit extensive, but this is a text representation of the call/response output...

```
dput(reply)

list(request = list(address = "33 Pratt Rd", citystatezip = "Scituate, MA"), 
    message = list(text = "Request successfully processed", code = "0"), 
    response = structure(list(name = "response", attributes = NULL, 
        children = list(results = structure(list(name = "results", 
            attributes = NULL, children = list(result = structure(list(
                name = "result", attributes = NULL, children = list(
                  zpid = structure(list(name = "zpid", attributes = NULL, 
                    children = list(text = structure(list(name = "text", 
                      attributes = NULL, children = NULL, namespace = NULL, 
                      namespaceDefinitions = NULL, value = "57223487"), class = c("XMLTextNode", 
                    "XMLNode", "RXMLAbstractNode", "XMLAbstractNode", 
                    "oldClass"))), namespace = NULL, namespaceDefinitions = NULL), class = c("XMLNode", 
                  "RXMLAbstractNode", "XMLAbstractNode", "oldClass"
                  )), links = structure(list(name = "links", 
                    attributes = NULL, children = list(homedetails = structure(list(
                      name = "homedetails", attributes = NULL, 
                      children = list(text = structure(list(name = "text", 
                        attributes = NULL, children = NULL, namespace = NULL, 
                        namespaceDefinitions = NULL, value = "http://www.zillow.com/homedetails/33-Pratt-Rd-Scituate-MA-02066/57223487_zpid/"), class = c("XMLTextNode", 
                      "XMLNode", "RXMLAbstractNode", "XMLAbstractNode", 
                      "oldClass"))), namespace = NULL, namespaceDefinitions = NULL), class = c("XMLNode", 
                    "RXMLAbstractNode", "XMLAbstractNode", "oldClass"
                    )), graphsanddata = structure(list(name = "graphsanddata", 
                      attributes = NULL, children = list(text = structure(list(
                        name = "text", attributes = NULL, children = NULL, 
                        namespace = NULL, namespaceDefinitions = NULL, 
                        value = "http://www.zillow.com/homedetails/33-Pratt-Rd-Scituate-MA-02066/57223487_zpid/#charts-and-data"), class = c("XMLTextNode", 
                      "XMLNode", "RXMLAbstractNode", "XMLAbstractNode", 
                      "oldClass"))), namespace = NULL, namespaceDefinitions = NULL), class = c("XMLNode", 
                    "RXMLAbstractNode", "XMLAbstractNode", "oldClass"
                    )), mapthishome = structure(list(name = "mapthishome", 
                      attributes = NULL, children = list(text = structure(list(
                        name = "text", attributes = NULL, children = NULL, 
                        namespace = NULL, namespaceDefinitions = NULL, 
                        value = "http://www.zillow.com/homes/57223487_zpid/"), class = c("XMLTextNode", 
                      "XMLNode", "RXMLAbstractNode", "XMLAbstractNode", 
                      "oldClass"))), namespace = NULL, namespaceDefinitions = NULL), class = c("XMLNode", 
                    "RXMLAbstractNode", "XMLAbstractNode", "oldClass"
                    )), comparables = structure(list(name = "comparables", 
                      attributes = NULL, children = list(text = structure(list(
                        name = "text", attributes = NULL, children = NULL, 
                        namespace = NULL, namespaceDefinitions = NULL, 
                        value = "http://www.zillow.com/homes/comps/57223487_zpid/"), class = c("XMLTextNode", 
                      "XMLNode", "RXMLAbstractNode", "XMLAbstractNode", 
                      "oldClass"))), namespace = NULL, namespaceDefinitions = NULL), class = c("XMLNode", 
                    "RXMLAbstractNode", "XMLAbstractNode", "oldClass"
                    ))), namespace = NULL, namespaceDefinitions = NULL), class = c("XMLNode", 
                  "RXMLAbstractNode", "XMLAbstractNode", "oldClass"
                  )), address = structure(list(name = "address", 
                    attributes = NULL, children = list(street = structure(list(
                      name = "street", attributes = NULL, children = list(
                        text = structure(list(name = "text", 
                          attributes = NULL, children = NULL, 
                          namespace = NULL, namespaceDefinitions = NULL, 
                          value = "33 Pratt Rd"), class = c("XMLTextNode", 
                        "XMLNode", "RXMLAbstractNode", "XMLAbstractNode", 
                        "oldClass"))), namespace = NULL, namespaceDefinitions = NULL), class = c("XMLNode", 
                    "RXMLAbstractNode", "XMLAbstractNode", "oldClass"
                    )), zipcode = structure(list(name = "zipcode", 
                      attributes = NULL, children = list(text = structure(list(
                        name = "text", attributes = NULL, children = NULL, 
                        namespace = NULL, namespaceDefinitions = NULL, 
                        value = "02066"), class = c("XMLTextNode", 
                      "XMLNode", "RXMLAbstractNode", "XMLAbstractNode", 
                      "oldClass"))), namespace = NULL, namespaceDefinitions = NULL), class = c("XMLNode", 
                    "RXMLAbstractNode", "XMLAbstractNode", "oldClass"
                    )), city = structure(list(name = "city", 
                      attributes = NULL, children = list(text = structure(list(
                        name = "text", attributes = NULL, children = NULL, 
                        namespace = NULL, namespaceDefinitions = NULL, 
                        value = "Scituate"), class = c("XMLTextNode", 
                      "XMLNode", "RXMLAbstractNode", "XMLAbstractNode", 
                      "oldClass"))), namespace = NULL, namespaceDefinitions = NULL), class = c("XMLNode", 
                    "RXMLAbstractNode", "XMLAbstractNode", "oldClass"
                    )), state = structure(list(name = "state", 
                      attributes = NULL, children = list(text = structure(list(
                        name = "text", attributes = NULL, children = NULL, 
                        namespace = NULL, namespaceDefinitions = NULL, 
                        value = "MA"), class = c("XMLTextNode", 
                      "XMLNode", "RXMLAbstractNode", "XMLAbstractNode", 
                      "oldClass"))), namespace = NULL, namespaceDefinitions = NULL), class = c("XMLNode", 
                    "RXMLAbstractNode", "XMLAbstractNode", "oldClass"
                    )), latitude = structure(list(name = "latitude", 
                      attributes = NULL, children = list(text = structure(list(
                        name = "text", attributes = NULL, children = NULL, 
                        namespace = NULL, namespaceDefinitions = NULL, 
                        value = "42.211625"), class = c("XMLTextNode", 
                      "XMLNode", "RXMLAbstractNode", "XMLAbstractNode", 
                      "oldClass"))), namespace = NULL, namespaceDefinitions = NULL), class = c("XMLNode", 
                    "RXMLAbstractNode", "XMLAbstractNode", "oldClass"
                    )), longitude = structure(list(name = "longitude", 
                      attributes = NULL, children = list(text = structure(list(
                        name = "text", attributes = NULL, children = NULL, 
                        namespace = NULL, namespaceDefinitions = NULL, 
                        value = "-70.775096"), class = c("XMLTextNode", 
                      "XMLNode", "RXMLAbstractNode", "XMLAbstractNode", 
                      "oldClass"))), namespace = NULL, namespaceDefinitions = NULL), class = c("XMLNode", 
                    "RXMLAbstractNode", "XMLAbstractNode", "oldClass"
                    ))), namespace = NULL, namespaceDefinitions = NULL), class = c("XMLNode", 
                  "RXMLAbstractNode", "XMLAbstractNode", "oldClass"
                  )), FIPScounty = structure(list(name = "FIPScounty", 
                    attributes = NULL, children = list(text = structure(list(
                      name = "text", attributes = NULL, children = NULL, 
                      namespace = NULL, namespaceDefinitions = NULL, 
                      value = "25023"), class = c("XMLTextNode", 
                    "XMLNode", "RXMLAbstractNode", "XMLAbstractNode", 
                    "oldClass"))), namespace = NULL, namespaceDefinitions = NULL), class = c("XMLNode", 
                  "RXMLAbstractNode", "XMLAbstractNode", "oldClass"
                  )), useCode = structure(list(name = "useCode", 
                    attributes = NULL, children = list(text = structure(list(
                      name = "text", attributes = NULL, children = NULL, 
                      namespace = NULL, namespaceDefinitions = NULL, 
                      value = "SingleFamily"), class = c("XMLTextNode", 
                    "XMLNode", "RXMLAbstractNode", "XMLAbstractNode", 
                    "oldClass"))), namespace = NULL, namespaceDefinitions = NULL), class = c("XMLNode", 
                  "RXMLAbstractNode", "XMLAbstractNode", "oldClass"
                  )), taxAssessmentYear = structure(list(name = "taxAssessmentYear", 
                    attributes = NULL, children = list(text = structure(list(
                      name = "text", attributes = NULL, children = NULL, 
                      namespace = NULL, namespaceDefinitions = NULL, 
                      value = "2019"), class = c("XMLTextNode", 
                    "XMLNode", "RXMLAbstractNode", "XMLAbstractNode", 
                    "oldClass"))), namespace = NULL, namespaceDefinitions = NULL), class = c("XMLNode", 
                  "RXMLAbstractNode", "XMLAbstractNode", "oldClass"
                  )), taxAssessment = structure(list(name = "taxAssessment", 
                    attributes = NULL, children = list(text = structure(list(
                      name = "text", attributes = NULL, children = NULL, 
                      namespace = NULL, namespaceDefinitions = NULL, 
                      value = "441300.0"), class = c("XMLTextNode", 
                    "XMLNode", "RXMLAbstractNode", "XMLAbstractNode", 
                    "oldClass"))), namespace = NULL, namespaceDefinitions = NULL), class = c("XMLNode", 
                  "RXMLAbstractNode", "XMLAbstractNode", "oldClass"
                  )), yearBuilt = structure(list(name = "yearBuilt", 
                    attributes = NULL, children = list(text = structure(list(
                      name = "text", attributes = NULL, children = NULL, 
                      namespace = NULL, namespaceDefinitions = NULL, 
                      value = "1972"), class = c("XMLTextNode", 
                    "XMLNode", "RXMLAbstractNode", "XMLAbstractNode", 
                    "oldClass"))), namespace = NULL, namespaceDefinitions = NULL), class = c("XMLNode", 
                  "RXMLAbstractNode", "XMLAbstractNode", "oldClass"
                  )), lotSizeSqFt = structure(list(name = "lotSizeSqFt", 
                    attributes = NULL, children = list(text = structure(list(
                      name = "text", attributes = NULL, children = NULL, 
                      namespace = NULL, namespaceDefinitions = NULL, 
                      value = "21400"), class = c("XMLTextNode", 
                    "XMLNode", "RXMLAbstractNode", "XMLAbstractNode", 
                    "oldClass"))), namespace = NULL, namespaceDefinitions = NULL), class = c("XMLNode", 
                  "RXMLAbstractNode", "XMLAbstractNode", "oldClass"
                  )), finishedSqFt = structure(list(name = "finishedSqFt", 
                    attributes = NULL, children = list(text = structure(list(
                      name = "text", attributes = NULL, children = NULL, 
                      namespace = NULL, namespaceDefinitions = NULL, 
                      value = "1363"), class = c("XMLTextNode", 
                    "XMLNode", "RXMLAbstractNode", "XMLAbstractNode", 
                    "oldClass"))), namespace = NULL, namespaceDefinitions = NULL), class = c("XMLNode", 
                  "RXMLAbstractNode", "XMLAbstractNode", "oldClass"
                  )), bathrooms = structure(list(name = "bathrooms", 
                    attributes = NULL, children = list(text = structure(list(
                      name = "text", attributes = NULL, children = NULL, 
                      namespace = NULL, namespaceDefinitions = NULL, 
                      value = "1.0"), class = c("XMLTextNode", 
                    "XMLNode", "RXMLAbstractNode", "XMLAbstractNode", 
                    "oldClass"))), namespace = NULL, namespaceDefinitions = NULL), class = c("XMLNode", 
                  "RXMLAbstractNode", "XMLAbstractNode", "oldClass"
                  )), bedrooms = structure(list(name = "bedrooms", 
                    attributes = NULL, children = list(text = structure(list(
                      name = "text", attributes = NULL, children = NULL, 
                      namespace = NULL, namespaceDefinitions = NULL, 
                      value = "3"), class = c("XMLTextNode", 
                    "XMLNode", "RXMLAbstractNode", "XMLAbstractNode", 
                    "oldClass"))), namespace = NULL, namespaceDefinitions = NULL), class = c("XMLNode", 
                  "RXMLAbstractNode", "XMLAbstractNode", "oldClass"
                  )), totalRooms = structure(list(name = "totalRooms", 
                    attributes = NULL, children = list(text = structure(list(
                      name = "text", attributes = NULL, children = NULL, 
                      namespace = NULL, namespaceDefinitions = NULL, 
                      value = "6"), class = c("XMLTextNode", 
                    "XMLNode", "RXMLAbstractNode", "XMLAbstractNode", 
                    "oldClass"))), namespace = NULL, namespaceDefinitions = NULL), class = c("XMLNode", 
                  "RXMLAbstractNode", "XMLAbstractNode", "oldClass"
                  )), zestimate = structure(list(name = "zestimate", 
                    attributes = NULL, children = list(amount = structure(list(
                      name = "amount", attributes = c(currency = "USD"), 
                      children = list(text = structure(list(name = "text", 
                        attributes = NULL, children = NULL, namespace = NULL, 
                        namespaceDefinitions = NULL, value = "472404"), class = c("XMLTextNode", 
                      "XMLNode", "RXMLAbstractNode", "XMLAbstractNode", 
                      "oldClass"))), namespace = NULL, namespaceDefinitions = NULL), class = c("XMLNode", 
                    "RXMLAbstractNode", "XMLAbstractNode", "oldClass"
                    )), `last-updated` = structure(list(name = "last-updated", 
                      attributes = NULL, children = list(text = structure(list(
                        name = "text", attributes = NULL, children = NULL, 
                        namespace = NULL, namespaceDefinitions = NULL, 
                        value = "06/17/2019"), class = c("XMLTextNode", 
                      "XMLNode", "RXMLAbstractNode", "XMLAbstractNode", 
                      "oldClass"))), namespace = NULL, namespaceDefinitions = NULL), class = c("XMLNode", 
                    "RXMLAbstractNode", "XMLAbstractNode", "oldClass"
                    )), oneWeekChange = structure(list(name = "oneWeekChange", 
                      attributes = c(deprecated = "true"), children = NULL, 
                      namespace = NULL, namespaceDefinitions = NULL), class = c("XMLNode", 
                    "RXMLAbstractNode", "XMLAbstractNode", "oldClass"
                    )), valueChange = structure(list(name = "valueChange", 
                      attributes = c(duration = "30", currency = "USD"
                      ), children = list(text = structure(list(
                        name = "text", attributes = NULL, children = NULL, 
                        namespace = NULL, namespaceDefinitions = NULL, 
                        value = "1494"), class = c("XMLTextNode", 
                      "XMLNode", "RXMLAbstractNode", "XMLAbstractNode", 
                      "oldClass"))), namespace = NULL, namespaceDefinitions = NULL), class = c("XMLNode", 
                    "RXMLAbstractNode", "XMLAbstractNode", "oldClass"
                    )), valuationRange = structure(list(name = "valuationRange", 
                      attributes = NULL, children = list(low = structure(list(
                        name = "low", attributes = c(currency = "USD"), 
                        children = list(text = structure(list(
                          name = "text", attributes = NULL, children = NULL, 
                          namespace = NULL, namespaceDefinitions = NULL, 
                          value = "448784"), class = c("XMLTextNode", 
                        "XMLNode", "RXMLAbstractNode", "XMLAbstractNode", 
                        "oldClass"))), namespace = NULL, namespaceDefinitions = NULL), class = c("XMLNode", 
                      "RXMLAbstractNode", "XMLAbstractNode", 
                      "oldClass")), high = structure(list(name = "high", 
                        attributes = c(currency = "USD"), children = list(
                          text = structure(list(name = "text", 
                            attributes = NULL, children = NULL, 
                            namespace = NULL, namespaceDefinitions = NULL, 
                            value = "500748"), class = c("XMLTextNode", 
                          "XMLNode", "RXMLAbstractNode", "XMLAbstractNode", 
                          "oldClass"))), namespace = NULL, namespaceDefinitions = NULL), class = c("XMLNode", 
                      "RXMLAbstractNode", "XMLAbstractNode", 
                      "oldClass"))), namespace = NULL, namespaceDefinitions = NULL), class = c("XMLNode", 
                    "RXMLAbstractNode", "XMLAbstractNode", "oldClass"
                    )), percentile = structure(list(name = "percentile", 
                      attributes = NULL, children = list(text = structure(list(
                        name = "text", attributes = NULL, children = NULL, 
                        namespace = NULL, namespaceDefinitions = NULL, 
                        value = "0"), class = c("XMLTextNode", 
                      "XMLNode", "RXMLAbstractNode", "XMLAbstractNode", 
                      "oldClass"))), namespace = NULL, namespaceDefinitions = NULL), class = c("XMLNode", 
                    "RXMLAbstractNode", "XMLAbstractNode", "oldClass"
                    ))), namespace = NULL, namespaceDefinitions = NULL), class = c("XMLNode", 
                  "RXMLAbstractNode", "XMLAbstractNode", "oldClass"
                  )), localRealEstate = structure(list(name = "localRealEstate", 
                    attributes = NULL, children = list(region = structure(list(
                      name = "region", attributes = c(name = "Scituate", 
                      id = "397319", type = "city"), children = list(
                        zindexValue = structure(list(name = "zindexValue", 
                          attributes = NULL, children = list(
                            text = structure(list(name = "text", 
                              attributes = NULL, children = NULL, 
                              namespace = NULL, namespaceDefinitions = NULL, 
                              value = "551,000"), class = c("XMLTextNode", 
                            "XMLNode", "RXMLAbstractNode", "XMLAbstractNode", 
                            "oldClass"))), namespace = NULL, 
                          namespaceDefinitions = NULL), class = c("XMLNode", 
                        "RXMLAbstractNode", "XMLAbstractNode", 
                        "oldClass")), links = structure(list(
                          name = "links", attributes = NULL, 
                          children = list(overview = structure(list(
                            name = "overview", attributes = NULL, 
                            children = list(text = structure(list(
                              name = "text", attributes = NULL, 
                              children = NULL, namespace = NULL, 
                              namespaceDefinitions = NULL, value = "http://www.zillow.com/local-info/MA-Scituate/r_397319/"), class = c("XMLTextNode", 
                            "XMLNode", "RXMLAbstractNode", "XMLAbstractNode", 
                            "oldClass"))), namespace = NULL, 
                            namespaceDefinitions = NULL), class = c("XMLNode", 
                          "RXMLAbstractNode", "XMLAbstractNode", 
                          "oldClass")), forSaleByOwner = structure(list(
                            name = "forSaleByOwner", attributes = NULL, 
                            children = list(text = structure(list(
                              name = "text", attributes = NULL, 
                              children = NULL, namespace = NULL, 
                              namespaceDefinitions = NULL, value = "http://www.zillow.com/scituate-ma/fsbo/"), class = c("XMLTextNode", 
                            "XMLNode", "RXMLAbstractNode", "XMLAbstractNode", 
                            "oldClass"))), namespace = NULL, 
                            namespaceDefinitions = NULL), class = c("XMLNode", 
                          "RXMLAbstractNode", "XMLAbstractNode", 
                          "oldClass")), forSale = structure(list(
                            name = "forSale", attributes = NULL, 
                            children = list(text = structure(list(
                              name = "text", attributes = NULL, 
                              children = NULL, namespace = NULL, 
                              namespaceDefinitions = NULL, value = "http://www.zillow.com/scituate-ma/"), class = c("XMLTextNode", 
                            "XMLNode", "RXMLAbstractNode", "XMLAbstractNode", 
                            "oldClass"))), namespace = NULL, 
                            namespaceDefinitions = NULL), class = c("XMLNode", 
                          "RXMLAbstractNode", "XMLAbstractNode", 
                          "oldClass"))), namespace = NULL, namespaceDefinitions = NULL), class = c("XMLNode", 
                        "RXMLAbstractNode", "XMLAbstractNode", 
                        "oldClass"))), namespace = NULL, namespaceDefinitions = NULL), class = c("XMLNode", 
                    "RXMLAbstractNode", "XMLAbstractNode", "oldClass"
                    ))), namespace = NULL, namespaceDefinitions = NULL), class = c("XMLNode", 
                  "RXMLAbstractNode", "XMLAbstractNode", "oldClass"
                  ))), namespace = NULL, namespaceDefinitions = NULL), class = c("XMLNode", 
            "RXMLAbstractNode", "XMLAbstractNode", "oldClass"
            ))), namespace = NULL, namespaceDefinitions = NULL), class = c("XMLNode", 
        "RXMLAbstractNode", "XMLAbstractNode", "oldClass"))), 
        namespace = NULL, namespaceDefinitions = NULL), class = c("XMLNode", 
    "RXMLAbstractNode", "XMLAbstractNode", "oldClass")))
```

I would expect the xmlValue function to output the "zestimate" (Zillow's estimated value for any given house) dollar value displayed as text for the XML element "amount" in the API response.

Thanks. Sorry for any unclarity or incorrect terminology!

Comment: Can you post the content of `reply` as well.

Comment: @Theo edits are above

Comment: You have to parse the XML content not the entire list: `doc = xmlTreeParse(reply$response, asText = TRUE, useInternal = TRUE)`

Comment: @Parfait I attempted to parse using both "reply$response" and "response$response" (in this second case, simply not assigning the variable "reply" and attempting to isolate the XML output from the) and both result in the error message "Error in (if (isHTML) warning else stop)(e) : bad error message"

Comment: Please `dput(reply)` into body of post as your sample may be missing levels.

Comment: @Parfait edits are above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am starting from the `response` which is my_xml. Essentially similar steps should get you to the `amount` even if you start from your xml.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(XML)

df_xml = xmlTreeParse(my_xml) 
df_root = xmlRoot(df_xml)

getNodeSet(df_root, "//amount") %>% unlist
```

With the new dput data, the following works.

```
df = dput(result) # essentially your df=result
df1 = df$response # there are three items in the list and response holds the info
getNodeSet(df1, "//amount") %>% unlist # this gets you a dataframe
```

Comment: Hi Theo, I tried your method, but I still receive an error when attempting to parse the response in the first line of code. The error is the one I first received when attempting this problem, "Error: XML content does not seem to be XML...". I think the issue is that the call/response output is not a usual XML file, or at least it cannot be manipulated in its current state by the usual XML R functions. Thanks for helping!

Comment: As a note: I have also attempted to write an XML file from the response provided by the API; I thought the response might be in the form of a dataframe, but when I attempted this change, it gave an error saying that the response is not a dataframe. So if it is in XML format but not a dataframe or an XML file, what is it?